# Virtualenv/Virtualenv wrapper placing env name in ZSH

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I just got ZSH and am getting it to work with Virtualenv and Virtualenvwrapper. Whenever I activate a env, the environment name gets repeated when I do not want it to. How can I turn off Virtualenv/wrapper's feature that places the environment name in my prompt so that I can recreate it in my .zshrc file?

Comment: What exactly were you trying to do here? I can't figure out if this is also my problem. What exactly does it mean to "disable the prompt"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply set the following envvar:

```
export VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1
```

Comment: I can't figure out if this is also my problem, just from the way this question was framed. What exactly does it mean in this case to "disable the prompt"?